# How to increase the length of cells in a single column in a table using HTML?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to increase the length of a single cell in a column.I tried using `<td style=\"length:100%;\">` But still its not working.

I'm using HTML code in a C code and hence CSS can't(?) help me out and so guys kindly help me on this issue?

Comment: Add an Inline style like this.. `<td style="width:200px">`

Comment: ^ that but it's worth noting that inline style is bad practice unless you have to have it for some reason. CSS is good.

Comment: @m59: Agree. I always use external CSS.:)

Comment: @m59: I'm using HTML code in C code and hence CSS can't help me out..

Comment: Y can't u guys promote my question if its good??

Comment: @Siva it isn't a good question. You could google the answer pretty quickly.

Comment: @m59 : ok.. My fate !

Comment: @Siva: If you wish, you can edit your question to say "I'm using HTML code in C code and hence CSS can't(?) help me out" and elaborate on what kind of solution you are looking for so that people here need not read all the comments!.

Comment: @Siva You shouldn't change your code, else this part in my answer **"Also, this length is an invalid property.. there is nothing like length in CSS, you need to use `width`"** becomes irrelevant

Comment: @Mr.Alien : Is this not a good question to promote? I edited it again..

Comment: @Siva Well, we don't promote questions here, you have doubts we solve it, people like it, they will surely upvote yours when they start looking for a similar problem :) though if you want I will upvote your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you increase the cells `width`, it will also change the `width` of other `table` cells as well...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6KXFT/)

So what to do now? You need to use `colspan` property, so that you can adjust the cell accordingly...

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/6KXFT/1/)

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Hello 2</td>
        <td>Hello 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="width: 200px;">Hello</td>
        <td>Hello 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you are expecting to change the `width` of a SINGLE cell, than that's not possible, it will change the widths of other cells in the column as well, if that's the case, than you need to use `div` instead of `table`

> Note: Am using `inline` CSS just for demo purposes, you can use a
>   `class` or `nth-child` pseudo to target that particular cell..

Also, this <s>`length`</s> is an invalid property.. there is nothing like <s>`length`</s> in CSS, you need to use `width`

Answer (score 0):

Increase the length or the width?

```
<td style="width:100%;"></td>
```

Or an actual width

```
<td style="width:10em;"></td>

<td style="width:300px;"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you intend to put two percent signs? And is there a reason for the escape characters? Oh, and length is not a valid property; what you want is width. Corrected, it would simply be:

```
<td style="width: 100%;">
```